# Using Index and Match Function to Match the Rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have written a formula Index Match function which takes the values from Row and pastes those values into Column by matching the criteria.

I want to loop through all data of `Sheet1` into formula then formula will match the `Sheet2 F9 cell` value with the `Sheet2 Col"B"` if the same value exists then copy the same row data and paste into `Sheet1 Col"F"` by matching the years and quarters.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D$4:$CH$4,MATCH(E10,Sheet1!$D$3:$CH$3,0))
```

Link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17p2D4aIUmncWouik3p4CJGnnJak8ZsaCBLJLHEo_sCA/edit#gid=1833309127

Comment: You index only row 4. If you want to match the column, add an extra comma before `MATCH`

Comment: Yes, i do not know how to create that formula to index the whole data of Sheet1 then match the Sheet2 cell F9 in sheet1 then copy same row data to paste into sheet2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$CH$8,match($F$9,Sheet1!$B:$B,0),MATCH(E10,Sheet1!$3:$3,0))`
Index by row and column match.